# How to show multiple markers on Google Map in react js?

Tags: google-maps, reactjs

I am using React js. Here is my code -

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import {GoogleMapLoader, GoogleMap, Marker} from 'react-google-maps';
import _ from 'lodash';

class MapContainer extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
        <section className="searchInput-MapScreen">
        <GoogleMapLoader
          containerElement={
            <div
              style={{
                height: `100%`
              }}
            />
          }
          googleMapElement={
            <GoogleMap
              defaultZoom={10}
              //defaultCenter={{ lat: latitude, lng: longitude }}
            >
            {_.map(this.props.areas, (a, i) => {
              let lat = parseFloat(a.lat.replace('"','').replace('"',''));
              let lon = parseFloat(a.lon.replace('"','').replace('"',''));
              console.log(lat)
              console.log(lon)
              return (
                <Marker key={i}
                  position={{ lat : lat, lng : lon }}
                  defaultAnimation={2}
                />
              )
            })}
            </GoogleMap>
          }
        />
      </section>
    )
  }
}

MapContainer.propTypes = {
  areas: PropTypes.array
}

export default MapContainer
```

The Google Map is not showing up. the latitude and longitude values are coming, you can see the console added in the code. But still the map doesn't appear on the page.

Comment: Please share how you are using this component. If there's a github or JSFiddle available, please share that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this myself.

For the sake of others, here is the solution to the above problem.

`defaultCenter={{ lat: latitude, lng: longitude }}`

This was commented in the above code which should not be as this one is required to show the map.

Latitude and Longitude for the default center can be hardcoded accordingly.

The new code will be -

```
    import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
    import {GoogleMapLoader, GoogleMap, Marker} from 'react-google-maps';
    import _ from 'lodash';

    class MapContainer extends React.Component {

      render() {
        return (
            <section className="searchInput-MapScreen">
            <GoogleMapLoader
              containerElement={
                <div
                  style={{
                    height: `100%`
                  }}
                />
              }
              googleMapElement={
                <GoogleMap
                  defaultZoom={10}
                  defaultCenter={{ lat: <somevalue>, lng: <somevalue>}}
                >
                {_.map(this.props.areas, (a, i) => {
                  let lat = parseFloat(a.lat.replace('"','').replace('"',''));
                  let lon = parseFloat(a.lon.replace('"','').replace('"',''));
                  console.log(lat)
                  console.log(lon)
                  return (
                    <Marker key={i}
                      position={{ lat : lat, lng : lon }}
                      defaultAnimation={2}
                    />
                  )
                })}
                </GoogleMap>
              }
            />
          </section>
        )
      }
    }

    MapContainer.propTypes = {
      areas: PropTypes.array
    }

    export default MapContainer
```

**To add some more info on this, I was using this component in order to search the areas using the postcode.
If the postcode is 2000, then it should mark all the areas on the map with this postcode.**

Hope this help someone else !

Thanks